# Do "声优" and "配音演员" mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning

Google Translate [gives "voice actors" for "声优"](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E5%A3%B0%E4%BC%98) and ["配音演员" for "voice actors"](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=zh-CN&text=Voice%20actors). Do "声优" and "配音演员" mean the same thing? Who is the most famous Chinese 声优?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

声优 is a loanword from Japanese. 配音演员 is Chinese original. They mean the same thing: voice cast. So usually 声优 refers to Japanese voice actors of Japanese animations. Chinese voice actors are rarely mentioned as 声优. But you can call a 声优 as (日本动漫)配音演员. So the usage of 配音演员 is more general, while 声优 is almost always  Japanese related.

Who is famous is opinion based and out of the range of this forum.

Answer (score 0):

声优 and 配音演员 are the same meaning, BUT
声优 is Japanese
配音演员 is Chinese. And Notice that 配音员 is more general in spoken language.

If you say 声优 to Chinese people, he know what you say and meaning, but it is not Chinese, it is foreign language to Chinese.

And I think he is the famous voice actor in great china area, almost every one heard his voice [林協忠](https://www.wikiwand.com/zh-tw/%E6%9E%97%E5%8D%94%E5%BF%A0)

Comment: I think 配音员 is more used in Taiwan, while 配音演员 is more used in PRC.